# Use of uninitialized value $args[0] in pattern match (m//) at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Parallel/ForkManager.pm line 73

Tags: perl

i have problem when i run perl script,

```
Use of uninitialized value $args[0] in pattern match (m//) at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Parallel/ForkManager.pm line 73. 
Missing required arguments: max_proc
```

any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing a number to the P::FM constructor, you did something equivalent to one of the following:

```
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new();
```

or

```
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(undef);
```

The entire point of P::FM is to limit the number of concurrent processes working on a problem, so you need to specify the limit!

Comment: my $forkmanager = new Parallel::ForkManager->new("100000");

this is ?

Comment: `new Parallel::ForkManager->new("100000")` is a bad way of writing `Parallel::ForkManager->new->new("100000")`, which is wrong for the reasons I mentioned.

Comment: same problem bro !
pls add me skype : lost.love.20
i have 3 days of trying and i didnt found soulotion !

Comment: The solution is to use `Parallel::ForkManager->new("100000")` instead of `new Parallel::ForkManager->new("100000")`